# "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'" error

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

Can someone help me about this issue? The first error was "value of type 'authdataresult' has no member 'uid'".

```
Auth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
```

So I removed the question mark to resolve the problem and it worked! But after that, another error came and it said "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'". I know, it's irritating.

```
self.userUid = user.uid
```

And oh, there's another error and it's been in my project for a very long time so now i'm ignoring it but then if someone knows how to fix it please let me know. The error is "only instance methods can be declared @ibaction".

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
```

I don't know why but maybe the 3 errors are connected. I don't know. Help.
So now I'm stuck again. Here is the whole messed up coding stuff.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var userUid: String!

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? userVC {
                if userUid != nil {
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }

        @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user,error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let user = user {
                            self.userUid = user.uid
                            self.goToCreateUserVC()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I swear, I tried to fix it and then 9 errors just popped out. By the way, I'm using Xcode 9, Swift 4, and my Cocoapods are up-to-date. To those all around people who edit, comment, or judge questions, please this is not a duplicate question. They are 2 different errors.

Comment: I fixed the indenting of your code so you can clearly see the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction" & "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Auth'" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316617/only-instance-methods-can-be-declared-ibaction-cannot-use-optional-chainin)

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Edit your original question if you have new information to add/clarify the question.

Answer (score 30):

It seems that Google has made some changes to Firebase Auth with the 5.0.0 update.
This worked for me:

```
self.userUid = user.user.uid
```

I'm not sure what was the point of the change but it still works exactly the same.

Comment: This is really weird. I just updated my pods after some time and had this error only in one place in my code. The rest of the places I used `user.uid` everything worked fine. I wonder why only one part of the code requires this `user.user.uid`

Comment: i guess it because it not always actually 'user' in completion. Mostly its AuthDataResult

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr Yes, that's actually what's happening. The `AuthDataResult` contains a `user` property. But the first "user" of "user.user" is actually an `AuthDataResult`.

Answer (score 4):

The new `Auth.auth().signIn` and `Auth.auth().createUser` methods use a datatype of `AuthDataResult?` instead of `User?`

The old callback was user of type: `User?`

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: User?, error) in
```

You would access properties directly on the callback user object such as:

```
if error == nil {
    if let user = user {
        self.userUid = user.uid
        // user.email for the email address in firebase
    }
}
```

The new callback is authDataResult of type: `AuthDataResult?`

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error) in
```

Now you access properties directly on the callback authDataResult object such as:

```
if error == nil {
    if let authDataResult = authDataResult {
        self.userUid = authDataResult.user.uid
        // authDataResult.user.email for the email address in firebase
    }
}
```

Basically the user object from the old way is now a property on the authDataResult object and you can get the uid through there:

```
authDataResult.user.uid
```

[Firebase's info  about AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult)

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let uid = user?.user.uid else {return}
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "")
let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some explanation, so that users can learn from your answer, instead of just copying&pasting code that may or may not work in their context.