# Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'?

Tags: swift

I am having trouble authenticating a user with the email because the system tells me "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'".

```
func handleRegister() {    

        guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}
        guard let name = nameTextField.text else {return}

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil
            {return}

            guard let uid = authResult.uid else {return}

            var ref: DatabaseReference!
            ref = Database.database().reference()
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if err != nil
                {return}

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: There should be a `)` after `password: password`

Comment: I add the ) after password: password, and the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'?", got solved but now I have a new error that says "Value of type 'AuthDataResult?' has no member 'uid"

Comment: That means that the authResult's class doesn't have a property for "uid".

Comment: Now see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360186/authdataresult-has-no-member-uid-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317730/value-of-type-authdataresult-has-no-member-uid-error?s=2|105.3088

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to call a String instead of a method().

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I wanted to know, how to call it by method in my code